# Replacing individual characters in excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have the Following code following recording a macro:

```
Sub RemoveLetters()

    Cells.Replace What:="C ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False, _
        FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2

End Sub
```

Which works fine to remove a single character from an active worksheet. The problem I have is that `C` is just one of a handful of common individual characters  I wish to remove How can I modify this or improve upon this to remove a list of given characters instead of just having to copy this for each?

Update:

Some of the data also contains units such as `°C`. The macro above unfortunately the above code recognises these characters as independent and therefore returns `°` only. Does anyone know how I can get around this?

Comment: FYI, this approach (and Tims answer) will also replace in Formulas.  This could break those Formulas.  Is this what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some parameters to your Sub and allow passing in an array of text items to be replaced:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    RemoveLetters ActiveSheet, Array("C ","D ","E ")
End Sub


Sub RemoveLetters(ws As Worksheet, arrTxt)
    dim i As Long
    for i=lbound(arrTxt) to ubound(arrTxt)
        ws.Cells.Replace What:=arrTxt(i), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False
    next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @chrisneilsen - you're right - I don't use that much from VBA. Reverted...   Some modification using `SpecialCells()` might resolve that formula issue...

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer. Ive just realised however that some of my data contains temperature units i.e. °C. Unfortunately both my code and your answer both remove the C here which I would wish to keep. Any ideas around this?

Comment: That's a bit more of a complex situation and would likely require you to loop over each cell and use a bit more logic to perform the replacements.

Comment: @Nick You could apply the same logic to exclude `"°C "` from partial deletion by changing 
this special occurrence to unused characters (e.g. `"°° "` instead of `""`) as first step, 
excecute Tim's `RemoveLetters` proc afterwards and
restore the mutilated tokens as final step (i.e. back from `"°° "` to `"°C "`).